# MidpointRounding in Math.Round not working correctly in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, rounding, math.round

The MidpointRound.AwayFromZero overload is supposed to round the 5 up in a rounding situation.

EX: `Math.Round(1.5, 1, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);`

This rounds 1.5 to 2.

However, when I try `Math.Round(1.025, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);` it rounds it down to 1.02. It is supposed to round up to 1.03 though.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value `1.025` cannot be represented exactly as the type `double`. Floating point numbers have that problem. See [Why are floating point numbers inaccurate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate).

When you write `1.025` as a `double` number, it will internally be a little bit smaller than `1.025`. That's why the rounding delivers an unexpected value.

When dealing with money or other stuff where you want the value be exactly the same as displayed, use the type `decimal` instead of `double`:

```
decimal roundedValue = Math.Round(1.025m, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

Note that the `m` after the number turns the number into a literal of the `decimal` type.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer! This fixed my issue entirely by converting the double into a decimal!